# select data from sql server using mvc framework with c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, oop

Its my first time to work on MVC framework and I am creating a shopping cart application.

I have three tables like `product`, `order`, `orderDetail`. First I configured only product and create a view using product control. when I run this I got an error like

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1
>   [MvcShoppingCart.Models.Product]', but this dictionary requires a model item of 
>   type 'MvcShoppingCart.Models.Product'.    "

If anyone have the solution please reply

Comment: Could you post your code on your product controller..

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code on the line where the error happens, to trace the circumstances of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception tells you that you pass an ObjectSet (from Entity Framework?) to a view as model where the view expects a Product instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to work on

[ASP.NET MVC TUTORIAL](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials)

This might help you to start.

Regards